# System.Net.Security.SslStream with HSM

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, cryptography, hsm

How to use .NET 4.8 System.Net.Security.SslStream with external device (HSM) that keeps private RSA keys secure, as SslStream.AuthenticateAsServer requires X509Certificate with both public/private keys. How can I associate X509Certificate private key with HSM and pass SslStream validation to the remote secure device?

Is it even possible with microsoft ssl abstraction or should I rely on some custom ssl implementation (open-source library)?

Comment: Create a service on remote machine that does the access to HSM.  Then connect to the service to access the device.  If the remote machine is IIS then the service would have to run as an admin.

Comment: What is the point of remote service? HSM's purpose is to never return plain keys. It will only return key cryptograms that have no usage on this issue. I need to somehow redirect X509Certificate validation to internal HSM structure.

Comment: So you can put the certificate on the same machine as the device that needs the certficate.

Comment: HSM does not need my certificate. It is the only place I can store private keys as per security requirements. And if I want to setup an SSL server with System.Net.Security.SslStream class, it requires me to input full RSA pair which is impossible on this case. Maybe there is a solution how to link X509Certificate class with the certificate stored on HSM device?

Comment: The private key is in the certificate.  The private key in your software and the private key in the HSM must be the same.  The private key does not need to be in a certificate, but usually it is.  You send a public key with the message and the public and private key are combined to encrypt/decrypt the message.  The reason for creating a service on the HSM machine you can access the certificate and encrypt/decrypt messages.

Comment: This is already a security flaw if I have a private key in my software that is identical to private key stored on HSM.

Comment: Ignore jdweng, he is a reliable source of misinformation on crypto.

Comment: Yeah, I was about to say similar.  "The private key is in the certificate".  Uh-huh.  No.  @RendoJack:  Does the HSM provider provide a CNG/CSP/KSP etc provider library. If so, and in general, you point the Windows subsystem at it as a valid provider of CNG/CSP/KSP operations.  Then, use that provider via the .Net (CNG) commands.  In specific, need to know which HSM you are using -- ask them, they may have an integration guide (ftr: yes, i work for one of them)

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know you architecture so I'm having issues give a good answer.  He are some pointers
1) Whenever you encrypt something you always need to decrypt (or verify).  So you always have two copies of the private key.  One where it is used to encrypt and the other where it is used to decrypt (or verify)

2) When a key is on a file system you can always protect the file using credentials.  But you cannot prevent somebody from remove the hard drive and reading on another system.  So a HSM give physical protection of the drive so somebody cannot read your private key on by removing the drive.
3)  You system has a red/black boundary where the red area is where data is not encrypted and black is where the data is encrypted.  You would have a firewall which is the division between red and black areas.  In you case you have three security areas where the third is a violet area (the HSM device) where the private key is protected.

The issue you are having is setting up the red/black/violet boundaries of your system.  You have red data that needs to be encrypted with a certificate that is on the HSM.  What I think you have is an internal red network (or database) with data that needs to be encrypted with the certificate before being sent out as encrypted black data.  So I'm recommending to have a service on the HSM that does the encryption.  So your red network to get data encrypted you would send to the encryption service.  Then after being encrypted the data could the be sent out the firewall as black data.